# Remove extra space before first col in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Before the first col, there is big space left, like I have used pull-1. Before the first row I have my navbar with margin-bottom:0;

Here is my code

```
 <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row" gpon-pic-area>
                                        <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: red">
                                            Inspection
                                                            <br>
                                                            <div class="rail-select gpon-pic-area">
                                                        <div class="select-side">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <select class="form-control gpon-pic-area" >
                                                                                            <option value="portStatus">Port Status</option>
                                                                    <option value="portAlarm">Port Alarm</option>
                                                                    <option value="portUsage">Port Usage</option>
                                                                    <option value="portBandwidth">Port Bandwidth</option>
                                                                                        </select>
                                                                    </div>
                                        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this all of the code?

Comment: No, but I just found solution. I increased the height of the navbar for 10px, and now it's good with margin-bottom. Probably it's a work around it

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about the space created by the container-fluid.

**With container-fluid**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row" gpon-pic-area>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: red">
      Inspection
      <br>
      <div class="rail-select gpon-pic-area">
        <div class="select-side">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
        </div>
        <select class="form-control gpon-pic-area">
                                                                                            <option value="portStatus">Port Status</option>
                                                                    <option value="portAlarm">Port Alarm</option>
                                                                    <option value="portUsage">Port Usage</option>
                                                                    <option value="portBandwidth">Port Bandwidth</option>
                                                                                        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Without container-fluid**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


  <div class="row" gpon-pic-area>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color: red">
      Inspection
      <br>
      <div class="rail-select gpon-pic-area">
        <div class="select-side">
          <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
        </div>
        <select class="form-control gpon-pic-area">
                                                                                            <option value="portStatus">Port Status</option>
                                                                    <option value="portAlarm">Port Alarm</option>
                                                                    <option value="portUsage">Port Usage</option>
                                                                    <option value="portBandwidth">Port Bandwidth</option>
                                                                                        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!